# no additive transparency for geom_line()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, transparency, alpha

I noticed when I use geom_line() and render to a pdf, the alpha transparency for lines is not additive (in contrast to geom_point(), which is). Is there anyway to get lines with additive transparency?

(looking to do something similar to http://andrewgelman.com/2012/08/26/graphs-showing-regression-uncertainty-the-code/ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code shows that line transparency in pdf output works on my setup:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat = data.frame(x1=0, x2=1, y1=rnorm(100), y2=rnorm(100))

p = ggplot(dat, aes(x=x1, xend=x2, y=y1, yend=y2)) +
    geom_segment(alpha=0.2, size=2)

ggsave("lines.pdf", plot=p, width=5, height=3)
```

[image]
Note: this image is png format but the pdf looks nearly identical on my system.

Your issue could be related to operating system or graphical device differences.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01)
Platform: i386-apple-darwin9.8.0/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_0.9.3.1
```

Comment: 2.15.3?! What is this, 2013?? :P